# Pandas DataFrame cleaning

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with birthday date like '10.10.1990'.
Since any method doesn't work with this column, I want to convert it to `datetime`. It work with first date column, but didn't work with the same second column.

I think the problem is with trash date in this columns, but I don't know how to clear it.

So, I'm using

```py
data[4] = pd.to_datetime(data[4], infer_datetime_format=True)
data[4].hist()
```

And, all is okay. But, when I'm doing the same thing on second column like first one I got an error:

> ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime.

I'm trying to look at this column with this methods:

```py
isna().sum()
Firs one: 6
Second one: 13

str.isnumeric().value_counts()
give a True: 2.
```

I want to know how to clear columns before working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default errors `kwarg` is 'raise' rather than 'ignore'.

Try using `date[4] = pd.to_datetime(date[4], infer_datetime_format=True, errors="ignore")`

or, `date[4] = pd.to_datetime(date[4], format='%d/%m/%Y', errors="ignore")` in case above doesnot work.

You can read more about different argument of `pandas.to_datetime()` [from](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `errors`

```
data[4] = pd.to_datetime(data[4], errors='coerce',format='%m.%d%.%Y')
```